# AST - parsing code of R programming language

Tags: r, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any good parser for R programming Language from which the abstract syntax tree can be derived? I noticed that there is the **lobstr** library from which the `ast()` function accepts expression as parameter. But this limits me, because I would like to get all the asts from every .r file that exists in a Project and I have not found any way where I can get the whole **.r file** as an expression.
 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know its possible or not to make the AST of while R script. But may be you can do other way around. You can read R script line by line, concat them and feed to lobstr. This is how you can get the AST. For example:

```
r <- '((r <- test*2)

      (r1 <- test1*4))'

bb <- str2lang(r)
lobstr::ast(!!bb)
```

output:

```
o-`(` 
\-o-o-`(` 
  | \-o-`<-` 
  |   +-r 
  |   \-o-`*` 
  |     +-test 
  |     \-2 
  \-o-`<-` 
    +-r1 
    \-o-`*` 
      +-test1 
      \-4
```

Or another way could be to generate tokens of the whole script and then analyze these tokens to fulfil your requirements.
Python script to make tokens:

```
with open("file.R", "rb") as source:
    for token in tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(source.read()).readline):
        print(token)
```

Not so good solution but may be work around if you didn't get any suitable solution yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I will try your suggestions and i will come back in a second time for the results!